# MS Word 2003 crashes with Office Tab installed

Tags: microsoft-office

I recently installed the Office Tab Free Edition 6.51 add-in for my MS Office 2003. Excel and PowerPoint worked well with Office Tab. But Word keeps on crashing at start-up. Disabling the add-in also doesn't work. A complete uninstall of the add-in make everything back to normal.

So what seems to be the problem of Word 2003 with the Office Tab add-in? I'm running Windows XP Professional SP3 on a Lenovo G460 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If it works without it, I guess it is a bad add-in!

You can try updating Office 2003 to the latest version, however it is most likely a compatibility issue.

Also, unless it is a proper crash, make sure you are using genuine software. Microsoft Office 2003 does force quit on some versions if it is not a legal copy.